# Java array giving "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6"

Tags: java, bubble-sort

Here is the source code.  I don't see any problems with this bubble sorting code:

```
int[] numbers = { 5, 8, 14, 1, 5678 };
int tempVar;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
   for(int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++)
   {
            if(numbers[i] > numbers[j + 1])
            {
                   tempVar = numbers [j + 1];
                   numbers [j + 1]= numbers [i];
                   numbers [i] = tempVar;
            }
   }
}
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
     System.out.println(numbers[i].toString());
}
```

Comment: numbers[] is a primitive int array. How can you call toString() on one of its elements?

Comment: This problem is very specific to what you're working on now, and I doubt it forms a corpus of useful knowledge.  My advice: use your debugger.  Walk through until the exception is thrown and you'll have your answer

Comment: Yeah, remove the .toString()

Comment: @Liam - I wanted to teach a man to fish, rather than giving him a fish.  Otherwise we're just encouraging people to outsource their trivial compiler/runtime errors to Stack Overflow...

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle good point, I didn't see your comment when I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Remove toString from the primitive array.Try the below code.

```
    int[] numbers = { 5, 8, 14, 1, 5678 };
    int tempVar;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    {
       for(int j = i+1; j < numbers.length; j++)
       {
                if(numbers[i] > numbers[j])
                {
                       tempVar = numbers [j];
                       numbers [j]= numbers [i];
                       numbers [i] = tempVar;
                }
       }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    {
         System.out.println(numbers[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown when you try to access the array over its defined length.  You are exceeding the array bounds in your loop.  And also the logic in the loop seems to be a bit wrong.  Try the following :

```
    int[] numbers = { 5, 8, 14, 1,5678};
    int tempVar;
    for (int i = 0; i < (numbers.length - 1); i++)
    {
       for(int j = 0; j < (numbers.length-1); j++)
       {
                if(numbers[j] > numbers[j + 1])
                {
                       tempVar = numbers [j];
                       numbers [j]= numbers [j + 1];
                       numbers [j+1] = tempVar;
                }
       }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    {
         System.out.println(numbers[i]);
    }
```